# phantomjs reading text file on windows

Tags: javascript, file, phantomjs, fs

I have a local .txt file on my windows machine and I want phantomjs to read from it. I tried

```
fs.open("C:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\out.txt" , 'r', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But it returns nothing just blank

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS does indeed has a file system module but it's much simpler than the one in node.js and it's synchronous:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.read('C:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\out.txt');
```

http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/read.html

Comment: I see you've recently started working with PhantomJS and have lots of questions, most of which you could figure out yourself just by reading docs. So why not add this page to your bookmarks? http://phantomjs.org/documentation/